# Problem with creating products - Shopify API

Tags: python, shopify

I'm having issues with the Shopify API POST /admin/api/2023-07/products.json endpoint. I received 200 when sending the JSON but it is not created on the web. I have creation permissions on the app, a valid authorization token, and well-formed JSON.

The response is the list of products that I have on the web and with an httCode 200.

CODE:

```
import requests

url = "URL.com/admin/api/2023-07/products.json"  


headers = {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "X-Shopify-Access-Token": ""
}

payload = {
  "product": {
    "title": "Burton Custom Freestyle 151",
    "body_html": "<strong>Good snowboard!</strong>",
    "vendor": "Burton",
    "product_type": "Snowboard"
  }
}


response = requests.post(url, headers=headers, json=payload)
```

Comment: Are you sending a PUT, POST or GET?

Comment: Reading the docs there's no reason to get a list of products with POST, can you post the code?